# c# TCP/IP server and client

Tags: c#, tcp

I want to write a similar program like the TCP/IP server and client but i want it to be web based, so on the clients side they can go on any web browser and be able to connect to the server.  How do i approach this, i want to use visual studio c#.  I looked up on web sockets, is that the way to go??

Comment: Im still new to this, but if i use silverlight, can i host the webpage so anyone can get on a computer and type in the URL address and acces the server?  ANd how can i do this, do i have to pay for it

Comment: Why do you want this TCP/IP server? For games?

Answer (score 0):

You could develop the client end in [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/), the server end would be able to be a standard C# console/winforms application.